# How does fog affect the conductivity/breakdown voltage of air?

Tags: meteorology, water, electromagnetism

Could the breakdown voltage of air significantly go down in very foggy weather (especially very salty fog from seawater)?  Kind of a hypothetical question, but if anyone has something on this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this considering that air is mostly nitrogen: "for gases (e.g. nitrogen, sulfur hexafluoride) it **normally decreases** with increased humidity." - "for air, [dielectric strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_strength) **increases slightly** as humidity increases"